# JavaScript: Why am I getting this AssertionError?

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, ecmascript-6, foreach

I have an index.js file that is implementing a `forEach` helper like so:

```
var images = [
  { height: 10, width: 30 },
  { height: 20, width: 90 },
  { height: 54, width: 32 }
];
var areas = [];
images.forEach(function(image) {
  return areas.push(image.height * image.width);
});

console.log(areas);

module.exports = images;
```

I know that solution works, you know that solution works, it works.

Then inside my test.js file:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const images = require("./index.js");
const expect = chai.expect;

describe("areas", () => {
  it("contains values", () => {
    expect([]).equal([300, 1800, 1728]);
  });
});
```

When I run `npm test`, I continue to get an AssertionError.

I will include the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my_tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "mocha": "6.0.2"
  }
}
```

I refactored my `test.js` file like so:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const areas = require("./index.js");
const expect = chai.expect;

describe("areas", () => {
  it("contains values", () => {
    const areas = [];
    expect(areas).equal([300, 1800, 1728]);
  });
});
```

Still getting the AssertionError:

```
AssertionError: expected [] to equal [ 300, 1800, 1728 ]
      + expected - actual

      -[]
      +[
      +  300
      +  1800
      +  1728
      +]
```

Comment: What is the actual error? Are you meaning to export `areas` not `images`?

Comment: @JackBashford, `areas` outputs `[300, 1800, 1728]` and so when I say `expect([]).equal([300, 1800, 1728]);`, it should be passing.

Comment: But `areas` is nowhere in your `test` file - you're exporting `images` from `index`, not `areas`.

Comment: @JackBashford, I tried that as well, but I am still getting an AssertionError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the Chai method that you're using. [Chai.equal](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal) does an identity comparison between the two arrays (`===`). Since the two arrays are not the same exact object in memory it will always fail, even if the contents are the same. You want the [Chai.eql](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql) which does a deep comparison of all the values.

```js
expect([1,2,3]).equal([1,2,3]) // AssertionError
expect([1,2,3]).eql([1,2,3]) // true
```

Comment: Taylor, your reasoning makes perfect sense but I am still getting the AssertionError even if I change `equal` for `eql`. I am saying the empty array should equal `[300, 1800, 1728]`, once the `forEach` has run its course.

Comment: The issue is that the `test.js` doesn't have access to the `areas` variable. It's declared inside of `index.js` and not exported. You're also comparing the literal empty array `[]` to a non-empty array. You should export `areas` and then change the `[]` to be `areas`, after you've changed the `const images` to `const areas`.